# how to update an image in my View Button, laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, model-view-controller

as I write in my controller that it should refresh a page in my View, in the case an image of a button...

my controller

```
public function getStatusLabelAttribute()
{
    if ($this->isActive()) {
        return "<label class='label label-success'>".trans('labels.general.active').'</label>';
    }
    return "<label class='label label-danger'>".trans('labels.general.inactive').'</label>';
}
```

my button

```
<div class="inputbutton">
 <span class="text">text</span>
 <input type="submit" class="btTxt submit" value=""  id="text" onclick="reply_click(this.id)"></div>
```

my css

```
div.inputbutton input {
background: url('/img/MYimg.png') no-repeat;
cursor: pointer;
width: 100px;
height: 130px;
border: none;
background-size: 100%;
}
```

my migration file

```
    Schema::create('chaves',function (Blueprint $table){
        $table -> increments('id');
        $table -> string('nome');
        $table -> boolean('alugado');
        $table -> timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: How are you calling the action/function you mentioned ? please post more code.

Comment: @TalhaAbrar, I updated the code

Comment: On what condition are you changing the image ?

Comment: the condition is to change a value in my mysql database, if 0 an image if 1 another image.

Comment: I'm assuming that you have a model for the table? in which image value is stored? 

Check this docs -> https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent

Comment: yes I have a model, but I write my codes in the controller, I change the value of boolean between 0 and 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170400/discussion-between-theflash-and-talha-abrar).